# Count rows that meet the criteria in a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a google sheet table (A-AB) with the following organization:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mggRbzANQQwAtf34rWLlNLP-AGrEQTmf2C-nxatP1Kw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

A search function that highlights the rows based on this formula works like a charm:

```
=AND( 
    OR($F$1="Any",countif($C4:$F4,$F$1)>0),1,
    OR($H$1="Any",countif($G4:$H4,$H$1)>0),1,
    OR($J$1="Any",countif($I4:$J4,$J$1)>0),1,
    OR($L$1="Any",countif($K4:$AB4,$L$1)>0),1,
    OR($N$1="Any",countif($K4:$AB4,$N$1)>0),1
)
```

Additionally, I've got a field that should show the number of results highlighted. That's where the issue is happening. I've tried using a simple COUNTIF but I get a result of 0. My best guess is that I'm using the wrong function.

```
=COUNTIF (C3:AB333, 
    AND( 
        OR($F$1="Any",countif($C4:$F4,$F$1)>0),1,
        OR($H$1="Any",countif($G4:$H4,$H$1)>0),1,
        OR($J$1="Any",countif($I4:$J4,$J$1)>0),1,
        OR($L$1="Any",countif($K4:$AB4,$L$1)>0),1,
        OR($N$1="Any",countif($K4:$AB4,$N$1)>0),1
    )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Updated with the picture of the sheet

Comment: The link has been added, hopefully, it will be helpful.

Comment: If j1 = "zoca" and all other selections are any -> count 2,
If j1 = "zoca" and h1= "zlaja" and other any -> count 0,
If j1 = "zoca" and h1= "vlaja" and other any -> count 3,
If n1 = "moca" and other any -> count 6
If n1 = "kep" and other any -> count 4

Comment: sorry, incomprehensible, I don't see any logic in that

Comment: Can you add the conditions that must be met in order for the count to get them? not sure what are you trying to accomplish with the `OR` and `countif`

Answer (score 0):

I've spent so much time searching for an answer and did not find a fitting one.

I've managed to bypass the issue by creating an additional column `AC` which basically contains the formula:

```
=AND(
    OR($F$1="Any",countif($C4:$F4,$F$1)>0),
    OR($H$1="Any",countif($G4:$H4,$H$1)>0),
    OR($J$1="Any",countif($I4:$J4,$J$1)>0),
    OR($L$1="Any",countif($K4:$AB4,$L$1)>0),
    OR($N$1="Any",countif($K4:$AB4,$N$1)>0)
)
```

in every column containing data that gives results `TRUE`/`FALSE` where the conditions are met and with a simple `countif` in the field where the counter is located on values `TRUE` in that column, the counter is working properly.

The question will remain open for a better answer because this is an ongoing project.

Comment: Can you share the code that you wrote to solve the problem.

Comment: I've posted the answer with everything I did to finish the sheet.